# One attribute in JSON in two separate columns

Tags: python, json, csv

I am fighting now with a problem how to split into two column in csv file something which looks like that:[image: Excelscreen]

I want to have in separate columns Price for Standard and Price for Convertible. However, they are under one attribute named 'aws:offerTermOfferingClass'. Do you know how to do it to have under one type of instance separate column with price for convertible and price for standard? I was trying with those ifs but it stops with error. Thank you very much for help in advance!

```py
import requests
import warnings
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')



regions=['ap-northeast-1','ap-south-1','ap-southeast-1','ap-southeast-2','eu-central-1','eu-west-1','eu-west-2','us-east-1','us-east-2','us-west-1','us-west-2']
OS=['linux','rhel','windows']

links=[]
for region in regions:
    for system in OS:
        links.append("https://a0.p.awsstatic.com/pricing/1.0/ec2/region/" + region + "/reserved-instance/" + system + "/index.json?")

superdict=[]

for link in links:
    print("Downloading data from: " + link)
    res=requests.get(link,verify=False).json()
    superdict.append(res)


df={"Region":[],"System":[],"Type":[],"Standard":[],"Convertible":[],"On demand":[]}



for res in superdict:
    for item in res['prices']:
        if item['attributes']['aws:offerTermLeaseLength']=="3yr" \
        and item['attributes']['aws:offerTermPurchaseOption']=="No Upfront":
            if item['attributes']['aws:ec2:operatingSystem']=="Linux" \
            and item['attributes']['aws:ec2:instanceType'].endswith('.large'):
                df["Region"].append(item['attributes']['aws:region'])
                df["System"].append("Linux/UNIX")
                df["Type"].append(item['attributes']['aws:ec2:instanceType'])
                df["On demand"].append(item['calculatedPrice']['onDemandRate']['USD'])
                if item['attributes']['aws:offerTermOfferingClass'] =="standard":
                    df["Standard"].append(float(item['calculatedPrice']['effectiveHourlyRate']['USD']))
                    df["Convertible"].append(np.NaN)
                elif item['attributes']['aws:offerTermOfferingClass'] =="convertible":
                    df["Convertible"].append(float(item['calculatedPrice']['effectiveHourlyRate']['USD']))
                    df["Standard"].append(np.NaN)





            elif item['attributes']['aws:ec2:operatingSystem']=="RHEL":
                df["Region"].append(item['attributes']['aws:region'])
                df["System"].append("Red Hat Enterprise Linux")
                df["Type"].append(item['attributes']['aws:ec2:instanceType'])
                df["On demand"].append(item['calculatedPrice']['onDemandRate']['USD'])
                if item['attributes']['aws:offerTermOfferingClass'] =="standard":
                    df["Standard"].append(float(item['calculatedPrice']['effectiveHourlyRate']['USD']))
                    df["Convertible"].append(np.NaN)
                elif item['attributes']['aws:offerTermOfferingClass'] =="convertible":
                    df["Convertible"].append(float(item['calculatedPrice']['effectiveHourlyRate']['USD']))
                    df["Standard"].append(np.NaN)

            elif item['attributes']['aws:ec2:operatingSystem']=="Windows":
                df["Region"].append(item['attributes']['aws:region'])
                df["System"].append("Windows")
                df["Type"].append(item['attributes']['aws:ec2:instanceType'])
                df["On demand"].append(item['calculatedPrice']['onDemandRate']['USD'])
                if item['attributes']['aws:offerTermOfferingClass'] =="standard":
                    df["Standard"].append(float(item['calculatedPrice']['effectiveHourlyRate']['USD']))
                    df["Convertible"].append(np.NaN)
                elif item['attributes']['aws:offerTermOfferingClass'] =="convertible":
                    df["Convertible"].append(float(item['calculatedPrice']['effectiveHourlyRate']['USD']))
                    df["Standard"].append(np.NaN)




data=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df)
data.to_csv(r'path_to_file.csv',index=False)
```

This is what I have now:
[image: Before]

And what I would like to have is:
[image: After]

Comment: Can you give the error you are getting ?

Comment: ```python ValueError: arrays must all be same length ``` I have something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problem are these lines in your `if`'s:

```
if item['attributes']['aws:offerTermOfferingClass'] =="standard":
    df["Standard"].append(float(item['calculatedPrice']['effectiveHourlyRate']['USD']))
elif item['attributes']['aws:offerTermOfferingClass'] =="convertible":
    df["Convertible"].append(float(item['calculatedPrice']['effectiveHourlyRate']['USD']))
```

With this you only fill one element in one of the list. That means after one iteration your dict `df` could look like this:

```
{"Region":["EU"],"System":["Windows"], \
  "Type":[3],"Standard":[12.00],"Convertible":[],"On demand":[8]}
```

After two iteration:

```
{"Region":["EU", "JAP"],"System":["Windows", "Linux/UNIX"], \
  "Type": [3,4],"Standard":[12.00],"Convertible":[18.00],"On demand":[8,13]}
```

So how should the dataframe look like? Standard and Convertible have only one element? everyone else have two. You can't build a df like this. And that is what the error is telling you: `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`

So basically a fix would be like this:

```
if item['attributes']['aws:offerTermOfferingClass'] =="standard":
    df["Standard"].append(float(item['calculatedPrice']['effectiveHourlyRate']['USD']))
    df["Convertible"].append(np.NaN) # or another default value
elif item['attributes']['aws:offerTermOfferingClass'] =="convertible":
    df["Convertible"].append(float(item['calculatedPrice']['effectiveHourlyRate']['USD']))
    df["Standard"].append(np.NaN)
```

## Merge rows if some values are blanks

What you can try is this after you created your dataframe:

```
df_ = df.replace('', np.nan).ffill().bfill()
pd.concat([
        df_[df_.duplicated()],
        df.loc[df_.drop_duplicates(keep=False).index]
    ])
```

Reference: [Python Pandas - merge rows if some values are blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733386/python-pandas-merge-rows-if-some-values-are-blank)

## Groupby

You can solve it with Groupby as well.

```
data = data.groupby(["Region","System","Type","On demand"]).sum().replace(0,np.nan)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It moreless works but I would like to have these values under one type of instance. Now this is still split but with empty value in Standard or Convertible column.

Comment: @Lukasz don't know what you mean under one type of instance.

Comment: @Lukasz how should the dataframe look like? what do you expect instead of an empty cell? you should provide example input with desired output.

Comment: now with code what you sent I have for example one row with specific name of instance and price only in one columnn let's say Standard. In the row below  I have name of the same type of instance but price value only in column Convertible. I would like to have one row instead of two with both prices.

Comment: @Lukasz that is what your code is doing. without an example input and output it's hard to understand what you really desire

Comment: @Lukasz with input I mean JSON

Comment: Ah ok. All of the files have structure like this one:https://a0.p.awsstatic.com/pricing/1.0/ec2/region/us-east-2/reserved-instance/linux/index.json

Comment: @Lukasz see my edit try it with that code fragment to merge your df on the blank values

Comment: @Lukasz check if the result is really what you want. I think groupby does what you want the other does something else!